# Doesn't Equal in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, select, equals

I am wondering if there is some way to do a doesn't equal command in MYSQL.  In other words, can you do a command like this: "SELECT * FROM someTitle WHERE someLabel != 'something'"?  My code is returning an error when I attempt this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `WHERE somelabel != 'something'` works fine for me on MySQL 4.1 - what is the error?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM someTitle WHERE someLabel <> 'something'
```

Answer (score 7):

Try <> instead of !=

Answer (score 5):

In SQL, like VB, `<>` is used instead of `!=`.

You can therefore write the following:

```
SELECT * FROM someTitle WHERE someLabel <> 'something'
```

I'm not sure how `<>` can mean inequality; can anyone explain?

Comment: Actually, `!=` is ANSI standard.

Comment: Well, if x is less than y or x is greater than y then x does not equal y.

Answer (score 4):

Use `someLabel <> 'something'` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Replace != with <>